# Ahadeth about zakat which contradicts and confuse me a lot

Tags: prophet-muhammad, zakat, sahih-bukhari, sahih-muslim, battles

Let me post hadith first and i will ask my question at last

It is from Sahih al-Bukhari

> Narrated Ibn 'Umar:
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: "I have been ordered (by Allah) to fight against the people until they testify that none has the right to be worshipped but Allah and that Muhammad is Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), and offer the prayers perfectly and give the obligatory charity, so if they perform that, then they save their lives and property from me except for Islamic laws and then their reckoning (accounts) will be done by Allah."
>
> حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ مُحَمَّدٍ الْمُسْنَدِيُّ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو رَوْحٍ الْحَرَمِيُّ بْنُ عُمَارَةَ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، عَنْ وَاقِدِ بْنِ مُحَمَّدٍ، قَالَ سَمِعْتُ أَبِي يُحَدِّثُ، عَنِ ابْنِ عُمَرَ، أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ أُمِرْتُ أَنْ أُقَاتِلَ النَّاسَ حَتَّى يَشْهَدُوا أَنْ لاَ إِلَهَ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ وَأَنَّ مُحَمَّدًا رَسُولُ اللَّهِ، وَيُقِيمُوا الصَّلاَةَ، وَيُؤْتُوا الزَّكَاةَ، فَإِذَا فَعَلُوا ذَلِكَ عَصَمُوا مِنِّي دِمَاءَهُمْ وَأَمْوَالَهُمْ إِلاَّ بِحَقِّ الإِسْلاَمِ، وَحِسَابُهُمْ عَلَى اللَّهِ ‏"‏‏.‏
>   Reference   : Sahih al-Bukhari 25
>   In-book reference    : [Book 2, Hadith 18](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/18)
>   USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Vol. 1, Book 2, Hadith 25
>     (deprecated numbering scheme)

Here is hadith from Sahih Muslim

> It is narrated on the authority of Abu Huraira that when the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) breathed his last and Abu Bakr was appointed as his successor (Caliph), those amongst the Arabs who wanted to become apostates became apostates. 'Umar b. Khattab said to Abu Bakr:
>
> Why would you fight against the people, when the Messenger of Allah declared: I have been directed to fight against people so long as they do not say: There is no god but Allah, and he who professed it was granted full protection of his property and life on my behalf except for a right? His (other) affairs rest with Allah. Upon this Abu Bakr said: By Allah, I would definitely fight against him who severed prayer from Zakat, for it is the obligation upon the rich. By Allah, I would fight against them even to secure the cord (used for hobbling the feet of a camel) which they used to give to the Messenger of Allah (as zakat) but now they have withheld it. Umar b. Khattab remarked: By Allah, I found nothing but the fact that Allah had opened the heart of Abu Bakr for (perceiving the justification of) fighting (against those who refused to pay Zakat) and I fully recognized that the (stand of Abu Bakr) was right.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا قُتَيْبَةُ بْنُ سَعِيدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا لَيْثُ بْنُ سَعْدٍ، عَنْ عُقَيْلٍ، عَنِ الزُّهْرِيِّ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنِي عُبَيْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عُتْبَةَ بْنِ مَسْعُودٍ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ لَمَّا تُوُفِّيَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم وَاسْتُخْلِفَ أَبُو بَكْرٍ بَعْدَهُ وَكَفَرَ مَنْ كَفَرَ مِنَ الْعَرَبِ قَالَ عُمَرُ بْنُ الْخَطَّابِ لأَبِي بَكْرٍ كَيْفَ تُقَاتِلُ النَّاسَ وَقَدْ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ أُمِرْتُ أَنْ أُقَاتِلَ النَّاسَ حَتَّى يَقُولُوا لاَ إِلَهَ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ فَمَنْ قَالَ لاَ إِلَهَ إِلاَّ اللَّهُ فَقَدْ عَصَمَ مِنِّي مَالَهُ وَنَفْسَهُ إِلاَّ بِحَقِّهِ وَحِسَابُهُ عَلَى اللَّهِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ فَقَالَ أَبُو بَكْرٍ وَاللَّهِ لأُقَاتِلَنَّ مَنْ فَرَّقَ بَيْنَ الصَّلاَةِ وَالزَّكَاةِ فَإِنَّ الزَّكَاةَ حَقُّ الْمَالِ وَاللَّهِ لَوْ مَنَعُونِي عِقَالاً كَانُوا يُؤَدُّونَهُ إِلَى رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم لَقَاتَلْتُهُمْ عَلَى مَنْعِهِ ‏.‏ فَقَالَ عُمَرُ بْنُ الْخَطَّابِ فَوَاللَّهِ مَا هُوَ إِلاَّ أَنْ رَأَيْتُ اللَّهَ عَزَّ وَجَلَّ قَدْ شَرَحَ صَدْرَ أَبِي بَكْرٍ لِلْقِتَالِ فَعَرَفْتُ أَنَّهُ الْحَقُّ ‏.‏
>   Reference    : Sahih Muslim 20
>   In-book reference    : [Book 1, Hadith 32](http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/32)
>   USC-MSA web (English) reference  : Book 1, Hadith 29
>     (deprecated numbering scheme)

My question is
Hadith from Sahih al-Bukhari says prophet Muhammed(pbuh) said that he will fight against the people untill they giving zakath

But hadith from Sahih Muslim says entirely different where when abu Bakr take sword aginst those who didnt give zakath .. Umar ibn al-Khattab saying to abu Bakr that prophet Muhammed said that we should not fight against the people of Muslims who beliefs in Allah and prophet... (Saying on node zakath is not that much important to fight)
as well as even abu Bakr didnt reply to 'Umar that 
"No! prophet messenger did say that to fight against zakath" 
instead abu Bakr said 
"By Allah zakath is also obligatory one so i will fight against them"

So my question is whether 'Umar and abu Bakr both forget what prophet Muhammed(pbuh) said about fight against people for zakath.. or I'm understanding in a differenr way??

Why Umar Khattab need to say Muhammed(pbuh) didn't mentioned anything about zakath??

Comment: What is zakath? I am not familiar with Arabic terms.

Comment: @RitaGeraghty maybe reading the tag info [tag:zakat] helps. Zakat is considered as one of the five pillars of Islam.

Comment: Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

I see no contradiction here.

The first hadith was narrated by ibn Umar, with no indication that Umar or Abu Bakr were even present to hear it. The second hadith being discussed is [narrated by multiple narrators](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/32-38), in meaning if not verbatim. The most obvious explanation is that these are simply two different statements said at two different times to two different audiences, and everyone involved is just speaking from their own knowledge of the Prophet's words.

Comment: Actually .. the second hadith was happened after the death of prophet ... I also heard maximum to maximum sahabas will other sahabas to know what prophet done in their absence... I think your seems to be illogic because here both umar and abu bakr seems that they dont know what prophet said ..

Comment: @musthafa It takes time for oral traditions to disseminate, and even longer to figure out the facts from the hearsay. It's not like they could just pick up a copy of Sahih Bukhari and learn everything right away.

Comment: So, whether companions of prophet has rights to take important decisions without knowing what prophet muhammed(pbuh) said?? Is it permissible .. because if you take second hadith where umar didnt know what to do by what those people said by quoting from quran ?? .. but abu bakr taking decision( as you said without knowing what prophet said) .. it means his own decision?? Whethere ir is permissible for sahabas